# Setting swt table column foreground color

Tags: java, colors, swt

Is there any way to set the SWT table column foreground and/or background colour?Or SWT table header foreground and background colour? setForeground/setBackground methods are not available on  **org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are `setBackground()` and `setForeground()` methods in [`TableItem`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FTableItem.html).

If you want to be able to customize the items more efficiently, I would recommend using `TableViewer` instead.

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html) is an excellent tutorial with a styling example.

---

Here is some sample code for a simple `Table` with a colored column:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.NONE);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);

    for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
    {
        TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
        column.setText("Column " + col);
    }

    Color color = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW);

    for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
    {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);

        for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        {
            item.setText(col, "Item " + row + " Column " + col);

            if(col == 1)
            {
                item.setBackground(col, color);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
    {
        table.getColumn(col).pack();
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

[image]

Comment: TableItems are the rows of table. Setting background/foreground colour will not set the table **header** foreground/background colour

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK You asked for background of columns **OR** headers. With the methods of `TableItem` it is possible to color a whole column (you don't have to color the whole row), except for the header, which is an OS component (so I doubt it can be colored).

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK [Here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=63038) is a bug report concerning the header color.

Comment: Yes I asked about setting the table header foreground background colours.I saw the bug but there is no update on this bug since long time. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK There are two more bug reports [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=242419) and [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=93129) that suggest that it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

No. it is not possible to set background/foreground on TableColumn ( depends on native support). you might have to custom draw the headers on your own.
make default header invisible and paint  your own headers in a separate canvas and you need to keep it in sync with with of `TableColumn` and scrolling of `Table`.

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.setHeaderVisible(boolean)
```